# CSS - Corner Radius with Box Shadow Inset, ugly corners

Tags: html, css

When I try to apply a box shadow to my element that has a 3px border radius I get ugly corners with pixels of the elements background.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">


</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}

#wrapper {
    background: black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 4px yellow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 4px yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 4px yellow;
}
```

JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/PCzFC/1/

If you look at the fiddle you see that the black background is in the corners. Is it supposed to be like this or is it a bug? I use Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in Google Chrome, perhaps it's present in Firefox as well.
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29427

Comment: A bug from 2009. bahhh!! Thx for info

Comment: Seems like it's an anti-aliasing issue in Firefox, can't really find a workaround in CSS.

Comment: anyone got the mozilla bug url?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the same effect without the inset. Make a yellow wrapper around it.

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}

#wrapper {
    background: black;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px black;
    margin: 5px;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 40px auto;
}​

<div class="yellow">
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PCzFC/65/

Answer (score 0):

What shadow: inset does is to add shadows inside the box. If you remove inset on all the box shadows, the shadows will move to the outside of the box.

Comment: what? I want the inset effect, but not the ugly corners..?

Answer (score -3):

it is not a bug this will happen because you use inset shadow effect and if you can understand css then inset meaning is inside so it's normal if u remove inset from your code then it should be look fine or if you need shadow effect inside the box then you have to choose color and matched it to box color 
or you can remove border radius from your code then it should be look fine

```
#wrapper {
    background: black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 4px yellow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 4px yellow;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 4px yellow;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what you're saying is that you shouldn't be using inset shadow when having round corners? excuse me but that sounds pretty stupid in my world. Why shouldn't I be able to have inset shadow when having round corners?

Comment: but if you using this then that corner issue is arise again and let me know how much css you know are you a expert