# Why background-color bleeds/leaks when using border-radius and an inset box-shadow?

Tags: background-color, css

This issue happens in ALL browsers. Mac or Windows, PC or mobile. It would be nice to have an expert in CSS rendering engines answering this since it doesn't look like an actual bug but a rendering issue instead.

HTML

```
<a>&nbsp;</a>
```

CSS

```
/* just for style */
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  /* using the next 3 rules together triggers the leak/bleed problem */
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 15px black;
  background-color: white;
  /* just for style */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5em;
}
```

CodePen demo: http://codepen.io/nunoarruda/pen/cbCxH

[image]

Comment: Check the CodePen demo. The background-color is leaking in the corners. I can't upload images as I don't have enough score for that yet.

Comment: Upload it and post it in a comment, we'll put it in the question for you

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot @apaul34208

Comment: Possibly the same issue as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580974/css-corner-radius-with-box-shadow-inset-ugly-corners).

Comment: @Harry yes it is the same issue but doesn't explain why ALL browsers have it

Comment: @NunoArruda: Absolutely mate. I was not saying that the other thread has a resolution but only that the same question had been asked before and probably (unfortunately) nobody has an answer. I myself would like to see an answer for this and hence didn't do close vote either :)

Comment: I've talked to a CSS expert and he said and I quote "The issue you raise is down to aliasing of pixels, I believe. It’s hard for rasterizers to that exactly right because of clipping algorithms." I think that's a reasonable explanation for this issue. Makes more sense to me now.