# unwanted corner when using border radius and box-shadow (inset)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having trouble trying to get rid of these annoying corners. Is there any way to use border-radius without having this problem?

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WYK5.png)]

```css
.buttons button{
    width: 150px;
    height: 65px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px 4px black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Suisse Int'l";
    background: #39C463;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

How to avoid the white corner problem when using border-radius

Comment: add your html..

Comment: looks like this is a [known bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13581772/7978627) in chrome. You could use a pseudo element to create the same effect but have more control over how it covers the border.

Comment: It's best if you edit your answer and use the snippet tool `<>` to load your css and html